# What will be the flow of execution in this node.js code?

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, node-modules, mean.io

Can anyone explain me flow of execution of this code and how...

//router file

```
/* GET home page. */
Class.getClasses(function(err,classes){
res.render('classes/index', { classes: classes });
},3);
```

//model

```
//fetch all classes
module.exports.getClasses = function(callback,limit){
Class.find(callback).limit(limit);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not familiar with the concept of callbacks, I take it? The logic here is simple. You have your handler

```
function(err,classes){
  res.render('classes/index', { classes: classes });
}
```

The rest of your code says "go find me some classes. When you do, call this function". And so you call `Class.getClasses` which calls `Class.find` which will invoke your handler when it's done.

Comment: If i had to simply this code so that i could understand it better... what would that be?

Comment: @ravi: I have no idea. :)